# Kubernetes apply to get to desired state

Tags: kubernetes

I feel like I have a terrible knowledge gap when it comes to managing the resource states within Kubernetes.

Suppose I have 2 deployments in my cluster, `foo1` and `foo2`. They are both defined in separate `yaml` files, `foo1.yaml` and `foo2.yaml` that are both inside a `my-dir` directory and have been applied with `kubectl apply -f my-dir/`

Now I want to make a third deployment, but also delete my second deployment. I know that I can do this in 2 steps:

- Make another `foo3.yaml` file inside the directory and then do `kubectl apply -f my-dir/foo3.yaml`
- Run `kubectl delete -f my-dir/foo2.yaml` to get rid of the second deployment.

My question is, can I do this in one shot by keeping the "desired state" in my directory. i.e. Is there any way that I can delete `foo2.yaml`, create a new `foo3.yaml` and then just do `kubectl apply -f my-dir/` to let kubernetes handle the deletion of the removed resource file as well? What am I missing here?

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but deployment-related which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This sounds very similar to what the [Helm](https://helm.sh) tool would do – if you created a `templates/foo3.yaml` and deleted `templates/foo2.yaml`, then `helm upgrade` would create the new Deployment and delete the old one.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way is to use some DevOps tools like jenkins, ansible or terraform for managing your deployments. If you don’t want to use external tools there is a [python library](https://kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for managing kubernetes. You can fetch the details of your kubernetes resources, deployments, pods etc., using this library you can also manage your kubernetes cluster. Similarly if you want to remove the deployment files  you just need to add a few more lines for deleting the file.